# Disabling codeigniter xss filtering or running over it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website and i've turned on global xss filtering and i've developed the website like this. I observed that i can't pass e-mails as get parameter no more . `ex: www.foo.com/data?email=example@dot.com`

I wonder how i can pass the email as parameter keeping the global xss filtering on, as i don't want to add a lot of `xss_clean('data')`.

I thought about splitting it in pieces like `www.foo.com/data?id=example&domain=dot&ext=com` but i don't know if this is the best idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: And you have discovered one reason why generically blacklisting input as a security feature sucks. Handle XSS properly. Implement suitable *escaping* on *output*.

Comment: It will be among my priorities. I want to launch the website and then i will do all the modifications while it's running so i will not spend anymore time offline. I knew from the beggining the downsides but this email part wasn't in my project in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you URL-encoding the email?

name@domain.com should become name%40domain.com

Comment: so in this form it should pass the xss filtering ?

Comment: No problem. [This](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) might be helpful. Any URL (regardless of whether it's user-input or generated) must have [special characters escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#List_of_allowed_URL_characters). CodeIgniter surely has a feature for that, check their docs/forum. If this is answered, please mark it so.